# Kafka Stream Avro Join on key

Tags: java, join, apache-kafka, avro

I am currently new to Kafka and I have some Troubles Kafka Streams and Avro.
First of all i have 2 Stream called "Observations" and "FeatureOfInterest". The Value of Observation contains the key of FeatureOfInterest. I want to merge them in a Output Topic with a join on Observation.value.get("Location") = FeatureOfInterest.key() [<-- Kafka key] but it get also be done with Observation.value.get("Location") = FeatureOfInterest.value.get("key").

The Output stream Contains all the Observation data + FeatureOfInterest.get("fields").

The output Stream should have the Same Avro schema just taht in the FeatureOfInterest Field is the "fields" json

Location and Oberservation are both in Avro Schema:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Observation",
  "namespace": "main.java.pw.oliver.jmkb.avroclasses",
  "doc": "An Observation represents a single Sensor reading of an ObservedProperty. A Sensor sends Observations to a specified Datastream.",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "iotId",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "iotId of this Observation"
    },
    {
      "name": "phenomenonTime",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "Time (ISO 8601) of the phenomenon"
    },
    {
      "name": "resultTime",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "Time (ISO 8601) of the result"
    },
    {
      "name": "result",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "Any result value represented as a string"
    },
    {
      "name": "resultQuality",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "doc": "Optional string describing the quality of the result"
    },
    {
      "name": "validTime",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "doc": "Optional time (ISO 8601) of validity"
    },
    {
      "name": "Datastream",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "Datastream associated with the Observation"
    },
    {
      "name": "FeatureOfInterest",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "doc": "Optional FeatureOfInterest associated with the Observation"
    }
  ]
}
```

FeatureOfIntreset

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "FeatureOfInterest",
  "namespace": "main.java.pw.oliver.jmkb.avroclasses",
  "doc": "In the case of remote sensing, the FeatureOfInterest can be the geographical area or volume that is being sensed.",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "iotId",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "iotId of this FeatureOfInterest"
    },
    {
      "name": "name",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "Name of the FeatureOfInterest"
    },
    {
      "name": "description",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "Description of the FeatureOfInterest"
    },
    {
      "name": "encodingType",
      "type": "string",
      "doc": "Representation/encoding type of the FeatureOfInterest"
    },
    {
      "name": "feature",
      "type": {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "LocationType",
        "doc": "The type of the location, for example Point",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "type",
            "type": "string",
            "doc": "Name of the LocationType"
          },
          {
            "name": "coordinates",
            "type": "string",
            "doc": "Coordinates for the LocationType"
          }
        ]
      },
      "doc": "LocationType object containing the feature of the Thing"
    },
    {
      "name": "Observations",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "doc": "Observations associated with this FeatureOfInterest"
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope you got my Question.

My Question is how i am gonne realise that.

And a other Question is, how i have to implement Avro as Serialization on the KStream.

```
    public class MergeB {

        private static final String ObservationTopic = "Observations";
        private static final String FeatureOfIntresssTopic = "FeaturesOfInterest";
        private static final String outputTopic = "ObservationsMerges";

        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {


            Properties props = new Properties();

            props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "192.168.56.3:9092");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "Merge");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "example-client");
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
            props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, GenericAvroSerde.class);
            props.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://192.168.56.3:8081");
            props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
            final Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
            final Serde<Long> longSerde = Serdes.Long();



         StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        final KTable<String, GenericRecord> foIT = builder.table(FeatureOfIntresssTopic);
        final KTable<String, GenericRecord> obsT = builder.table(ObservationTopic);
        obsT.mapValues(value -> {

            String obsIot = value.get("FeatureOfInterest").toString();
                    System.out.println(obsIot);

                    foIT.mapValues(value1 -> {
                       String foiIot =  value.get("iotId").toString();
                        Boolean test = obsIot.equals(foiIot);
                        System.out.println(obsIot + " " + foiIot + " " + test);

return value1;
                    });



return value;
                }


        );








            KafkaStreams kafkaStreams1 = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);
            kafkaStreams1.start();

            Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(() -> {
                kafkaStreams1.close();

            }));



        }
```

That should work ? but my Programm is not going in that FoIt.mapValues

Comment: Confluent has a github repo on Avro serialization in Streams API. Assuming you're using the Schema Registry

Comment: Yes i am using a Schema Registry Server. And it Works with a Client Consumer. simply add   props.put(VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.class"); 

but how does it works with Kafka Stream

Comment: Meanwhile I got it to use Serdes from Avro

Comment: Works the same way. Search for serde https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WikipediaFeedAvroExample.java

Comment: I edit it and postet my code. What to do in with Join Method

Comment: I have not used the streams api before, but this link has a left join example https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/5.0.0-post/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/PageViewRegionExample.java Alternatively, you can use KSQL to write that join more easily

Comment: Hi @JoeDaniel, Were you able to make it work ?
Any hints, I'm also trying to achieve the same task of joining tables. And am using schema-registry.

Comment: ehm its way too long ago :D